# Order and Group rows in Mysql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Iam trying to execute the following mysql query and getting mentioned error.

```
SELECT * FROM `selector` WHERE `to_id`='44' ORDER BY `time` DESC 
GROUP BY `event_id`, `entity_guid`;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds  to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near  'GROUP BY `event_id`, `entity_guid` LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Can anybody help to correct/rewrite this query as I need to order the rows in descending order first `time` and then eliminate the duplicate entries by grouping `event_id` and `entity_guid`

Below is the representation of my `SELECTOR` table

```
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------|
|fr_id | to_id | event_id | entity_guid | time        |
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------|
| 44   | 54    |  4       | 0           | 1531121058  |
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------|
| 54   | 44    |  3       | 0           | 1531063718  |
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------|
| 54   | 44    |  2       | 609         | 1531063431  |
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------|
| 54   | 44    |  1       | 608         | 1530975443  |
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------| 
| 150  | 44    |  1       | 608         | 1531542247  |
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------|
```

The actual result I needed is as follows

```
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------| 
| 150  | 44    |  1       | 608         | 1531542247  |
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------|
| 54   | 44    |  3       | 0           | 1531063718  |
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------|
| 54   | 44    |  2       | 609         | 1531063431  |
|------|-------|----------|-------------|-------------|
```

Comment: if i remember correctly should be first group and then order...

Comment: Learn how to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are misusing MySQL's non-standard extension to `GROUP BY`. Please read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Your query is likely to yield unpredictable results.

Comment: Well I suspect max() will return only one result not the expected result of  ORDER BY DESC (more than 1 results) based on to_id

Comment: Good call on the dup, @Barmar !

Comment: I have updated the how actual results needs to be, please check

Comment: Actually the pointed one was not infinite, written query as my own way and achieved the accurate result, Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

The `ORDER BY` clause goes after the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: already tried that, but it is not providing expected result, first I need to order them in descending by using time (timestamp) then group them

Comment: SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM `selectors` WHERE `to_id`='44' 
     ORDER BY `time` DESC) as d GROUP BY d.event_id, d.entity_guid; 
even the above query failed

Comment: @Thomas Ordering doesn't affect how grouping is done, why do you think you need to do it first?

Comment: yep, I need to display the results based on timestamp using ORDER BY DESC, so the latest added rows will displayed first, then eliminate the duplicated rows, look at my table format, so the actual result needed is eliminate the second last row by displaying the last row eg.fr_id =150 (based on time stamp)

Comment: For my question the result can be achieved using following query, for the information of attendees in this thread
`SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE (to_id,time) IN(SELECT to_id, MAX(time) 
FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE to_id='id' GROUP BY `entity_guid`, `event_id`) 
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0,3 `

Comment: @Thomas when you answer your own question on StackOverflow, it's customary to write an Answer.  Why? StackOverflow is, at its heart, an archive of questions and answers. Comments don't get indexed as efficiently.

Comment: @Jon Thanks, yes I know but I am unable to answer my question :(

Answer (score 0):

Your Query should be like this

```
SELECT `event_id`, `entity_guid` FROM `selector` 
WHERE `to_id`='44'
    GROUP BY `event_id`, `entity_guid`
     ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

If you need more help then please share your data set and expected output

Comment: Thanks, but why not * ,not only event_id entity_guid? not expecting that

Comment: there is some rules for using group by think you need to know those rules 1st